# multiple HashMap implementation

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the use of two HashMaps and it seems to be more or less successful also.But now my problem is i want to update the value of a hashMap based on a check.ie if userId is already existing in the hash i need to update the timestamp corresponding to it...

Below given is my code.How can we accomplish the updation of values .Can that be done usiong setValue..?but how..?please help me friends..

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  HashMap sessionTimeStampHash = new HashMap<Long, Long>(); //sessionID is the key and timeStamp is the value
  //userID is the key and sessionTimeStampHash object is the value
  HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, Long>> userSessionHash = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, Long>>();

  sessionTimeStampHash.put("sessionID", "timeStamp");
  userSessionHash.put("userID", sessionTimeStampHash);
  // System.out.println(userSessionHash);
  sessionTimeStampHash = new HashMap();

  sessionTimeStampHash.put("sessionID1", "timeStamp1");
  userSessionHash.put("userID1", sessionTimeStampHash);
  //  System.out.println(userSessionHash);
  sessionTimeStampHash = new HashMap();
  sessionTimeStampHash.put("sessionID2", "timeStamp2");
  userSessionHash.put("userID2", sessionTimeStampHash);
  //   System.out.println(userSessionHash);
  sessionTimeStampHash = new HashMap();
  sessionTimeStampHash.put("sessionID3", "timeStamp3");
  userSessionHash.put("userID3", sessionTimeStampHash);
  //   System.out.println(userSessionHash);


  for (Entry<String, HashMap<Long, Long>> entry : userSessionHash.entrySet())
  {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    String userId = "userID3";
    if (key.equals(userId))
    {
      System.out.println("Check Successful");
      String TimeStamp = newTime;
      entry.setValue() // how can i change my timeStamp
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You declare `sessionTimeStampHash` as a `Map<Long, Long>` but you do `sessionTimeStampHash.put("sessionID1", "timeStamp1");` are you putting in `Long` values or `String` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without for loop

```
if(userSessionHash.get(userId)!=null)
  userSessionHash.get(userId).put(userSessionHash.get(userId).keySet().toArray[0], timestamp);
```

Comment: hi..Nishant ...i relly accept that idea without usage of forloop.But ....keySet().toArray[0],...is not applicable since userSessionHash.put() referes to another usage...can u suggest any other idea..?

Comment: @vidhya not sure, if I understand correctly. Do you want to (1) update the existing sessionId's timestamp, which is one sessionId per userId, (2) Are there more than one sessionId per userId? And you want to update all the timestamps for all the sessionIds of a userId; Or (3) you wanted to insert a new sessionId and a new timestamp for the given userId? Clarify a bit.

Comment: hi..Nishant...the 1st option is my requirement ie update the existing sessionId's timestamp, which is one sessionId per userId,

Comment: @vidhya yeah, this solution will do fine, it will just update the user's *existing* sessionId's timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Loop on your second map (I assume you want to update all the sessionIds for the user) and modify the value.

```
if (key.equals(userId)) 
{
    System.out.println("Check Successful");
    String TimeStamp=newTime;

    for ( String sessionId : entry.getValue().keySet() )
    {
       entry.put(sessionid, timeStamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String userId = "userID3";
Long timeStamp =  userSessionHash.containsKey(userId) ? userSessionHash.get(userSessionHash) : 0;
userSessionHash.put(userId,new AtomicLong(request.getSession(false).getMaxInactiveInterval()))
```